# Geoserver Status Screen

Tags: geoserver

Can anyone tell me what all the information on this Geoserver status this means and if there are any issues with it?

I cannot find anything in the documentation that explains what all this is actually telling us.

We have figured out the reload button, but not sure if it is required for EVERY configuration change or not, but we generally press it after changing anything, including styles, GeoWebCache changes, layer changes, etc.

Thanks in advance

Mark

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to press reload, changes are saved automatically. The button is there mostly for people making direct changes on the config files on the file system, and to allow for a sort of "soft restart" without having to bounce the container.

During "normal" operations none of the buttons in this page is of use.